# Getting started with STM32F4 with Keil

Tags: stm32, keil

I bought a STM32F410RB Nucleo board which has a [STM32F410RB Cortex-M4 MCU](http://www2.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32f4-series/stm32f410/stm32f410rb.html). I'm trying to program it with Keil but I didn't find any example for my board. All examples are for other nucleo boards.
I don't know why keil examples don't supply examples for my board, maybe I missed something. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean the examples don't support your board? STM provides loads of examples for Nucleo boards, and you should be able to run them given you configure Keil to use the correct chip.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [link](http://www2.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software/stm32cubef4.html) and download the software at the bottom.

Once downloaded, unzip it, and inside ./Projects/STM32F410xx-Nucleo/ there's everything you need to test your board. You dont even need to create a project from scratch, because inside each example folder, there's a folder named "MDK-ARM" which contains the Project configuration file for Keil5. happy hacking

Answer (score 0):

There's a comprehensive step by step guide to run your program using CMSIS on http://www.keil.com/appnotes/docs/apnt_268.asp, which is accompanied by 6 videos. Also for starters The definitive guide to cortex m3 and cortex-m4 book is a must. You can find more sources on Keil site and also ARM university.